# How to include py file based on the command line input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command

My python script has to include other python scripts in the code. And I want the other scripts to be passed as command line arguments. 
For example:
My script is test.py, and I want to include first.py in my code based on the command line input.
Command line input

> > > python test.py first.py

In the code I want first.py to be imported as in:

import first

But I can't figure out a way. I tried using optparse and fileInput, but they didn't turn out to be what I had intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is best practice to import module from arguments, but if you really want to do that, could try below code:

```
import sys

for file_name in sys.argv[1:]:
    module_name = file_name.replace('.py', '')
    exec('import %s' % module_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the best way to answer your question. But here is my solution. Again, this may not be the best solution-

```
module_name = input()

with open('file_name.py', 'w') as py_file:
    py_file.write('import ' + module_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't a simple import statement in the original code do the job? Like so:

```
import first
#
# The rest of the program.
#
```

Then from the command line, you only need to run

```
python test.py
```

As long as test.py and first.py are in the same directory, this approach is effectively "including" first.py in test.py. Please include more information about why you want to pass first.py as a command line argument. It seems to me, since you already know what your program will be doing with first.py, and you have to write your code under the assumption that first.py will be imported anyway, you might as well just do it at the beginning of test.py.

Comment: It does. But I want the end user to decide which file he wants to provide to my test script. Yeah my sentence structure was vague but what I want to say is I do not know which file I will have to import.

Comment: What will the test script do with the user input? You can't use any classes or functions from the user's input since you don't know what they'll input, so what's your end goal?

Answer (score 0):

> python test.py first.py - In this case, test.py is argv[0] and first.py is argv[1]

Add below code in your test.py

```
from sys import argv
execfile(argv[1])
```