# ImportError: No module name <module name>

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, import-module

I am using following piece of code in python:

```
name_of_module  = abc

from name_of_module import *
```

But I am getting following error:

> ImportError: No module named name_of_module.

Please help

Comment: Please provide the name of the module, operating system, python version...

Comment: Name of the module is atets_timeset_database

Comment: operating system is unix

Comment: You sure? I can't even find it on google

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if atets_timeset_database module exists. Even if it exists try importing it directly. Assigning it to other variable and using the variable in import may not work

Comment: Hi Its a python script inside my current working directory.

Comment: I wanted to import this python script to my existing python script.

Comment: >>import importlib
>>moduleName = "script" #( without .py extension)
>>importlib.import_module(moduleName)

Comment: suppose the python script which i want to import is 'abc.py'
then I am assigning it to a variable name_of_module = abc
and then callimg using 
from name_of_module import *
I am getting error that name_of_module module doesnt exist

Comment: you can use `exec`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001691/how-to-include-py-file-based-on-the-command-line-input/48001847#48001847) is an example